# Error:The ConnectionString property has not been initialized?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have used this piece of code for connecting to the database..It is showing error like The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

```
Dim sConnString As String = "user id=" + sUserID + ";password=" + sPwd + ";initial catalog=" + sDatabase + ";Connect    Timeout = 30" + ";Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=" + MaxPoolSize + ";Min Pool Size=" + MinPoolSize + ";"

            Dim Conn As New SqlConnection()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NEC_Customer_Mst(Customer_Code,Customer_Name) VALUES(Customercode,Customername)"
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            Conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Conn.Close()
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your code so that you use a `using` statement.  This way it will clean up resources when it has finished.

```
Dim sConnString As String = "user id=" + sUserID + ";password=" + sPwd + ";initial catalog=" + sDatabase + ";Connect Timeout=30;Pooling=true;Max Pool Size=" + MaxPoolSize + ";Min Pool Size=" + MinPoolSize + ";"              

Using Conn As New SqlConnection(sConnString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand()             
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NEC_Customer_Mst(Customer_Code,Customer_Name) VALUES(Customercode,Customername)"             
        cmd.Connection = Conn             
        Conn.Open()             
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I gave it like that it is showing error like System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'connect timeout'.

Comment: @bala3569: You can try `Connection Timeout` or `Timeout`

Comment: @bala3569: I also notice that you aren't specifying a `Server` or a `Data Source`.

Answer (score 2):

You declared your connection string `sConnString`, but forgot to pass the connection string to `SqlConnection()`:

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(sConnString)
Conn.Open()
```

Comment: I gave it like that it is showing error like System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'connect timeout'.

Comment: at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)

Comment: @bala: It's `Connect Timeout`, with only one space.

Comment: Your connection string has more than one space between the words Connect and Timeout. That is probably the problem.

Comment: @bala3569: ... your connection string is `sConnString`.

Comment: Now got this error-----System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: In sql server it is getting connected but not through this

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was not initialized:

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(sConnString)
Conn.Open()
```

Comment: I gave it like that it is showing error like System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'connect  timeout'.

Comment: at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)

Answer (score 0):

Connection Sting Property Error always occur when the connection is not declared/renewed

the solution is simple

```
dim con as new SqlConnection 
con.connectionString = "Provide your SQL connection"
con.open
'write code or action you want to perform
con.close
```

Hope it helps.